Making a plot of a complicated function, without solving the relationships
I am hoping to have a sense of the value of y, which depends on variables a, r, and c. For tasks like that, the only way I know is to use Plot or Plot3D with Manipulate.
However, the relationship here is too complicated, so I could not Solve for y.
Is there a way I can make a plot of y without solving it first?
y == (r - a c (2 + r) - 
3 a r (-1 + (-a c (1 + 2 r) y - r (-1 + y) (-1 + 4 a y) + 
    c^2 (1 - (1 + a) y + 2 a (1 + r) y^2) + 
    Sqrt[(c^2 - r)^2 - 
     2 ((c^2 - r)^2 + 
        a (-1 + c) c (c^2 + r (-3 + 2 r))) y + ((c^2 - r)^2 + 
        a^2 (-1 + c)^2 (c^2 + 8 r^2) + 
        2 a (-1 + c) c (c^2 + r (-3 + 2 r))) y^2])/(
   2 a (-2 r + c^2 (1 + r)) (-1 + y) y)) + 
c^2 (-r + ((2 + r) (-a c (1 + 2 r) y - r (-1 + y) (-1 + 4 a y) + 
      c^2 (1 - (1 + a) y + 2 a (1 + r) y^2) + 
      Sqrt[(c^2 - r)^2 - 
       2 ((c^2 - r)^2 + 
          a (-1 + c) c (c^2 + r (-3 + 2 r))) y + ((c^2 - r)^2 + 
          a^2 (-1 + c)^2 (c^2 + 8 r^2) + 
          2 a (-1 + c) c (c^2 + r (-3 + 2 r))) y^2]))/(
   2 (-2 r + c^2 (1 + r)) (-1 + y) y)) + 
Sqrt[-1 + c] Sqrt[
 r] \[Sqrt]((-1 + c) (1 + c)^2 r + 
    2 a (r + c (2 - (2 + c) r) + 
       1/(2 a (-2 r + c^2 (1 + r)) (-1 + y) y) (-1 + c) (1 + 
          c)^2 r (-a c (1 + 2 r) y - r (-1 + y) (-1 + 4 a y) + 
          c^2 (1 - (1 + a) y + 2 a (1 + r) y^2) + 
          Sqrt[(c^2 - r)^2 - 
           2 ((c^2 - r)^2 + 
              a (-1 + c) c (c^2 + r (-3 + 2 r))) y + ((c^2 - 
                r)^2 + a^2 (-1 + c)^2 (c^2 + 8 r^2) + 
              2 a (-1 + c) c (c^2 + r (-3 + 2 r))) y^2])) + 
    a^2 (-8 + 4 c - r + 5 c r + 
       1/(a (-2 r + c^2 (1 + r)) (-1 + y) y) (r + 
          c (2 - (2 + c) r)) (-a c (1 + 2 r) y - 
          r (-1 + y) (-1 + 4 a y) + 
          c^2 (1 - (1 + a) y + 2 a (1 + r) y^2) + 
          Sqrt[(c^2 - r)^2 - 
           2 ((c^2 - r)^2 + 
              a (-1 + c) c (c^2 + r (-3 + 2 r))) y + ((c^2 - 
                r)^2 + a^2 (-1 + c)^2 (c^2 + 8 r^2) + 
              2 a (-1 + c) c (c^2 + r (-3 + 2 r))) y^2]) + 
       1/(4 a^2 (-2 r + c^2 (1 + r))^2 (-1 + y)^2 y^2) (-1 + 
          c) (1 + c)^2 r (-a c (1 + 2 r) y - 
          r (-1 + y) (-1 + 4 a y) + 
          c^2 (1 - (1 + a) y + 2 a (1 + r) y^2) + 
          Sqrt[(c^2 - r)^2 - 
           2 ((c^2 - r)^2 + 
              a (-1 + c) c (c^2 + r (-3 + 2 r))) y + ((c^2 - 
                r)^2 + a^2 (-1 + c)^2 (c^2 + 8 r^2) + 
              2 a (-1 + c) c (c^2 + 
                r (-3 + 2 r))) y^2])^2)))/(2 a (-2 r + 
  c^2 (1 + r)) (-1 + (-a c (1 + 2 r) y - r (-1 + y) (-1 + 4 a y) +
    c^2 (1 - (1 + a) y + 2 a (1 + r) y^2) + 
   Sqrt[(c^2 - r)^2 - 
    2 ((c^2 - r)^2 + 
       a (-1 + c) c (c^2 + r (-3 + 2 r))) y + ((c^2 - r)^2 + 
       a^2 (-1 + c)^2 (c^2 + 8 r^2) + 
       2 a (-1 + c) c (c^2 + r (-3 + 2 r))) y^2])/(
  2 a (-2 r + c^2 (1 + r)) (-1 + y) y)))


expr=y-RightHandSide;NMinimize[{expr^2,-10<y<10,-10<r<10,-10<c<10,-10<a<10},{a,c,r,y}] in 10 seconds finds a,c,r,y that is almost exactly y==RightHandSide
